# Load content into parent element with jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a div element with a specific ID

```
<div id='someid'>
    <input type='submit' class='edit' value='Edit'>
</div>
```

When the button is pressed, I want to select the parent element (in this case the div element) and load content into it. I've tried:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".edit").click(function(){
    var id = $(this).parent().get(0).id;
    $(id).load("contentpage");
  });
});
```

But this doesn't work, presumably because I am not selecting the parent in the right way? If I print out the id variable, it does have the right value ('someid'), but I guess $(id) is where I am wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason it's not working is because your selector is "someid" instead of "#someid", but there is a simpler way:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".edit").click(function(){
    $(this).parent().load("contentpage");
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Just daisy chain the call.  You are not selecting the ID correctly.

```
$(this).parent().load("contentpage")
```

Answer (score 1):

You don’t need to use another query, `parent` already returns the parent element:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".edit").click(function(){
    $(this).parent().load("contentpage");
  });
});
```